# Selenium 2 WebDriver FireFiox WHY am I still getting this error

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This has been giving me hell for a full day now. I have tried installing older versions or both WebDriver and FireFox, i cant escape this error! help would be greatly appreciated!

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1     on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID:
```

Comment: could you specify in your tags, whether you are trying Selenium 1 or Selenium 2. judging by your question, looks like Selenium 2

Comment: Does your `/etc/hosts` file contain any mappings to `127.0.0.1` other than `localhost`?

Comment: What version of firefox and selenium do you have installed?

Comment: sircapsalot: Selnium 2

Comment: Slanec: I also have ::1

Comment: Amey: I have currently FireFox 19, but Ive tried almost every version between 7 - latest in the last 2 days

Comment: @AnthonyJ.Neal Excuse me? I obviously don't know what `::1` means. Anyway, if it's another mapping to `127.0.0.1` in your `hosts` file, try to remove (change) it, reboot and try again.

Comment: @Slanec Please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855063/selenium-webdriver-error-cannot-open-display-99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is clearly indicating the incompatibility between firefox browser version and selenium version. Please take update for both, this will get resolve easily.

I have also faced the same personally and there are lots of examples on the web like [link1](http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2012/11/orgopenqaseleniumfirefoxnotconnectedexc.html#.UilZ7dLfBN8) or sometimes antivirus is also blocking the same like [link2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5881)

I have faced the same issue when I have updated the firefox browser to the latest one but not the selenium version. As soon as I have updated that, my framework runs smoothly.

Comment: Thanks @Sankumarsingh! I had to walk away from this and come back to it. It looks like AVG anti-virus was blocking the ports used by WebDriver. I changed the antivirus I was using, and it works just fine now.

Comment: please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855063/selenium-webdriver-error-cannot-open-display-99

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self explanatory.

Upgrade FF
Upgrade selenium version

Do a mvn clean compile

If it still doesn't work, try to delete the .m2/repository/* contents and then do a clean compile/install

This worked for me.